Change Lists/ObservableCollection in one DataGrid
I want to display a List/ObservableCollection in a DataGrid in a WPF application. At the push of a button, a different list should be displayed, but it is a list of a different data type. It works without databinding, but I would like to change the GUI to MVVM/Databinding.
XAML:
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Width="400" />

Example Code:
        public void test(bool changeList)
        {
            ObservableCollection<type1> list1 = new ObservableCollection<type1>();
            ObservableCollection<type2> list2 = new ObservableCollection<type2>();
            ObservableCollection<T> MyList;

            if (changeList)
            {
                MyList = list1;
            }
            else
            {
                MyList = list2;
            }
        }

I know I still need to use RaisePropertyChanges, etc.
How can I access a general list/ObservableCollection?
Without databinding, I got the desired result:
xaml:
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
          IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=CbDisableList}"
          CurrentCellChanged="DGChangedList"/>

Example Code
            if (changeList)
            {
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = list1;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = list2;
            }


Declare a view model property of type IEnumerable and assign either list1 or list2.

Thank you for your time and effort, now it works
